# Firebase (Firestore) getting ref value async - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have to admit, it the most strange bug that i saw in TypeScript-JavaScript (I got Model class in TypeScript and ReactJS Component in JS...) . I have a list of *Promo* Object, inside this one a property "_listCompte" which is a list of *Compte* Object.

The list of *Promo* is created by retrieving data from database, all works at this point

[image: Console]

After that i got a *forEach* on *listPromo* and it works, but when i try to iterate with *forEach* on a *listCompte* it's looks like is empty.

[image: Console2]

ReactJS Component :

```
class DettesView extends Component{
state = {
    loading: true,
    activeItem: "DI4",
    listPromo: []
};


componentDidMount() {
    let listPromo = [];
    FirebaseAPI.getDatabase().collection("Promo")
        .onSnapshot((docSnapshot)=>{
            docSnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                const promoData = doc.data();
                let promo = Promo.fromData({
                    nom: promoData.nom,
                    promoId: promoData.promoId
                });
                promoData.listCompte.forEach((compteRef)=>{
                    compteRef.get()
                        .then((doc)=>{
                            if(doc.exists){
                                let compte = Compte.fromData(doc.data());
                                promo.addCompte(compte);
                            }
                        }
                    )
                });
                listPromo.push(promo);
            });
            console.log("listPromo", listPromo);
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                status: true,
                listPromo: listPromo
            });
        }, (error)=>{
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                status: false,
                errorMessage: error.getMessage(),
                errorCode: error.getCode()
            });
        });
}

toggleTabs = tab => () => {
    if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
        this.setState({
            activeTab: tab
        });
    }
};

render() {
    const {loading, listPromo} = this.state;
    if(loading)
        return (
            <MDBContainer fluid>
                <MDBRow center={true}>
                    <MDBCol size="2" className="mt-5">
                        <MDBCard>
                            <MDBCardBody>
                                <img src={gifLoading} alt="gif-loading"/>
                                <h1 className="mt-4 text-center">Loading...</h1>
                            </MDBCardBody>
                        </MDBCard>
                    </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>
            </MDBContainer>
        );
    else if(this.state.status)
        return (
            <div className="classic-tabs">
                <MDBNav classicTabs color="cyan">
                    {listPromo.map((value, index) => (
                        <MDBNavItem key={index}>
                            <MDBNavLink to="#" active={this.state.activeItem === value.nom} onClick={this.toggleTabs(value.nom)}>
                                {value.nom}
                            </MDBNavLink>
                        </MDBNavItem>
                    ))}
                </MDBNav>
                <MDBTabContent
                    className="card"
                    activeItem={this.state.activeItem}
                >
                    {listPromo.map((value, index) => {
                        console.log("value of property 'listCompte' in a 'Promo' object", value.listCompte);
                        console.log("size of property 'listCompte' in a 'Promo' object", value.listCompte.length);
                        return (
                            <MDBTabPane tabId={value.nom} key={index}>
                                <MDBTable hover>
                                    <MDBTableHead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Prénom</th>
                                            <th>Nom</th>
                                            <th>Promo</th>
                                            <th>Dette</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </MDBTableHead>
                                    <MDBTableBody>
                                        {value.listCompte.map((valueCompte, indexCompte) => {
                                            console.log("compte", valueCompte);
                                            return (
                                                <tr key={indexCompte}>
                                                    <td>{valueCompte.nom}</td>
                                                    <td>{valueCompte.prenom}</td>
                                                    <td>{value}</td>
                                                    <td>{valueCompte.dette}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            )
                                        })}
                                    </MDBTableBody>
                                </MDBTable>
                            </MDBTabPane>
                        )
                    })}
                </MDBTabContent>
            </div>
        );
    else
        return (
            <MDBContainer fluid>
                <MDBRow center={true} className="mt-3">
                    <MDBCol size="6">
                        <MDBCard>
                            <MDBCardBody>
                                <img src={gifError} alt="gif-error" className="text-center img-fluid"/>
                                <h2>Erreur &#128551; : {`${this.state.errorCode}`}</h2>
                                <h4>=> {`${this.state.errorMessage}`}</h4>
                            </MDBCardBody>
                        </MDBCard>
                    </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>
            </MDBContainer>
        );
}
```

}

(I already tried to use *map* instead of *forEach* but it didn't work). If someone got an idea, thanks

Promo TS-Class :

```
interface PromoData {
    promoId: string;
    nom: string;
}

class Promo {
private _nom: string;
private _promoId: string;
private _listCompte: Array<Compte>;

constructor(proId: string, nom: string) {
    this._nom = nom;
    this._promoId = proId;
    this._listCompte = new Array<Compte>();
}

get listCompte(): Array<Compte> {
    return this._listCompte;
}

addCompte = (value: Compte) => {
    this._listCompte.push(value);
};

get promoId(): string {
    return this._promoId;
}

set promoId(value: string) {
    this._promoId = value;
}

get nom(): string {
    return this._nom;
}

set nom(value: string) {
    this._nom = value;
}

static fromData(promoData: PromoData): Promo{
    return new this(
        promoData.promoId,
        promoData.nom
    );
}

logError() : void {
    console.log(this._listCompte);
    this._listCompte.forEach((compte: Compte)=>{
        console.log(compte)
    })
}
```

}

And Compte TS-Class

```
interface CompteData {
    promoId: string;
    nom: string;
    prenom: string;
    dette: number;
    isKefet: boolean;
    compteId: string;
}

class Compte {
private _nom: string;
private _prenom: string;
private _dette: number;
private _promoId: string;
private _isKefet: boolean;
private _compteId: string;

constructor(compteId: string, nom: string, prenom: string, dette: number, isKefet: boolean, promoId: string) {
    this._compteId = compteId;
    this._nom = nom;
    this._prenom = prenom;
    this._dette = dette;
    this._promoId = promoId;
    this._isKefet = isKefet;
}

get compteId(): string {
    return this._compteId;
}

set compteId(value: string) {
    this._compteId = value;
}

get nom(): string {
    return this._nom;
}

set nom(value: string) {
    this._nom = value;
}

get prenom(): string {
    return this._prenom;
}

set prenom(value: string) {
    this._prenom = value;
}

get dette(): number {
    return this._dette;
}

set dette(value: number) {
    this._dette = value;
}

get isKefet(): boolean {
    return this._isKefet;
}

set isKefet(value: boolean) {
    this._isKefet = value;
}

static fromData(compteData: CompteData): Compte{
    return new this(
        compteData.compteId,
        compteData.nom,
        compteData.prenom,
        compteData.dette,
        compteData.isKefet,
        compteData.promoId,
    )
}
```

}

(All of my properties got getter and setter)

------- Additional Test -------

By adding a *console.log* of *listPromo* in render

[image]

Comment: You will need to show the code where you call `addCompte` and use `forEach`. Since you are grabbing data from a database sounds like this may be an async issue.

Comment: Most likely -> [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: try initialising the array _listCompte as [] and not by using the class constructor

Comment: I'm use Firebase as Cloud firestore database, and it's Promise "oriented"

Comment: @voiys I already tried and it fix nothing :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an async issue. You are retrieving the `compteRef`s asynchronously, but you are not waiting until they are retrieved before calling `setState()` in `componentDidMount`, and you are not calling `setState()` after they are finally retrieved.

Please try this. This should properly wait until all async requests have finished before calling `setState()`:

```
preparePromo(doc) {
    const promoData = doc.data();

    let promo = Promo.fromData({
        nom: promoData.nom,
        promoId: promoData.promoId
    });

    return Promise.all(promoData.listCompte.map((compteRef) =>
        compteRef.get()
    )).then((comptes) => comptes
        .filter(compte => compte.exists)
        .forEach(compte => promo.addCompte(Compte.fromData(compte.data())))
    ).then(() => promo);
}

componentDidMount() {
    FirebaseAPI.getDatabase().collection("Promo")
        .onSnapshot((docSnapshot)=>{
            Promise.all(docSnapshot.map(this.preparePromo))
                .then((listPromo) => {
                    console.log("listPromo", listPromo);

                    this.setState({
                        loading: false,
                        status: true,
                        listPromo: listPromo
                    });
                });
        }, (error)=>{
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                status: false,
                errorMessage: error.getMessage(),
                errorCode: error.getCode()
            });
        });
}
```

Please pardon if I have any mistmatched parentheses or anything. I have no way of testing this.

Also, if you are amenable to using `async`/`await`, this code can be made a bit cleaner:

```
async preparePromo(doc) {
    const promoData = doc.data();

    let promo = Promo.fromData({
        nom: promoData.nom,
        promoId: promoData.promoId
    });

    const comptes = await Promise.all(promoData.listCompte.map((compteRef) =>
        compteRef.get()
    ));

    comptes
        .filter(compte => compte.exists)
        .forEach(compte => promo.addCompte(Compte.fromData(compte.data())));

    return promo;
}

componentDidMount() {
    FirebaseAPI.getDatabase().collection("Promo")
        .onSnapshot(async (docSnapshot) = >{
            const listPromo = await Promise.all(docSnapshot.map(this.preparePromo));

            console.log("listPromo", listPromo);

            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                status: true,
                listPromo: listPromo
            });
        }, (error)=>{
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                status: false,
                errorMessage: error.getMessage(),
                errorCode: error.getCode()
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Ok it doesn't work, but i think it's indeed the good way. The line "await Promise.all(docSnapshot.map(this.preparePromo));" doesn't retrun an array (it's undefined return). Maybe an idea to fix it ?

Comment: Just add `return` before `comptes.filter...` in `preparePromo`

Comment: @JustinMartinDev As mayakwd points out, it's probably the missing `return` that's the issue. I've added it now.

Comment: @mayakwd Thanks. I actually needed to return `promo`, since the `comptes.filter...` bit only has side-effects.

Comment: @JLRishe Thank you, it's works. I did not realize that I could have a problem of asyncronism.